# When should I whitelist a Security group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have a Security-group `Apple` which is attached to my application EKS worker nodes i.e. EC2 instances.
I have another Security-group `Mango` which is attached to the database EC2 instance, also EKS cluster.

When I whitelist `Apple` Security-group in `Mango`, the applications in my EKS cannot access the db.

But when I explicitely whitelist the IP's of the worker nodes i.e. the EC2 instances, the applications can access the database.

Why does this work? Shouldn't whitelisting the attached Security-group solve my use case?
Please help.

Comment: Is the database address an internal VPC IP or a public IP?

Comment: @gusto2 public IP

Comment: The security groups won't work with public IP as an sg reference. Basically - the service "sees" a client from a public IP address and is unable to match it with another AWS resource / security group. The SG reference works with the internal VPC addresses. In this case the RDS access needs to be inside the VPC (if you want the SG reference working).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the rules of a Security Group refer to another Security Group, traffic will be permitted but **only for the private IP address of instances**.

If you are referring to the public IP address of the EC2 instance with the database, then the traffic goes out of the Internet Gateway and back 'into' the VPC. The source identity is therefore lost and the Security Group will not permit the inbound traffic.

You should communicate within the VPC by using private IP addresses.